# looking for an application launcher that doesn't launch the same app twice?

Tags: launcher

i recently switched from windows to linux and installed an **application launcher** called Albert,
if i have an app **running** (ex:chrome or vscode) if i type the **same** app name in alfred it will open a **new window** . i'm looking for a launcher that will open a new window if the app is **not running** on, otherwise it will **redirect** you to the **already running window**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior of most launchers is to have the launched application handle things. Launchers will just "launch" the application, even if it might already be open. In many cases, that results in a new instance of the application. In other cases, the application is programmed to check for existing instances, and instead do something with an existing window if one exists. As an example, Gimp will "sense" if it is already running, and switch to the existing instance rather than launching a new instance.

This is fitting in a concept of separating "launching" from "switching to", which some people might prefer. Whenever you want to go to an existing instance, you switch to it. When you look to start up a new instance, you launch. You always know the launcher will give you a new instance. Some people may prefer that, but others, like you, might prefer differently.

There is in fact a launcher that is a notable exception: it is the launcher of the default Ubuntu Desktop, which uses "Gnome Shell". This launcher does use the "Launch or Switch to" model you are after.

So I can answer your question already in a simple way: the launcher that doesn't launch the same app twice is **the default launcher of your Ubuntu desktop**.

You prefer to use Albert (probably that is what you mean rather than Alfred, which is the OS X counterpart Albert was inspired upon) because it is lightweight, fast and elegant. Having a "Launch or Switch to" feature is on the roadmap of Albert. Currently, it does not do that. Still, this is Linux, and one can hack to have the behaviour you want with Albert or any other launcher. There is some inspiration in this [10 year old question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13582/command-to-activate-either-run-or-bring-to-front-if-already-running-a-program), but there is a more simple way not mentioned there.

The most simple approach is to launch your command with a one-liner like:

```
wmctrl -a Calculator || gnome-calculator
```

This checks, using the utility `wmctrl` whether there is a window "Calculator". If that fails, the second command is executed, the command to launch the application. If `wmctrl` would not be installed on your system, then you can install it with the command `sudo apt install wmctrl`.

In practice, you would edit the `.desktop` launcher, a little text file that is used by your launcher to start an application. These files live (among others) in `/usr/share/applications`. For example, `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Calculator.desktop` contains, among others, following line.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Calculator
Comment=Perform arithmetic, scientific or financial calculations
Exec=gnome-calculator
Icon=org.gnome.Calculator
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;Calculator;
```

The `Exec=` line defines how the application is launched. So if you replace

```
Exec=gnome-calculator
```

by

```
Exec=sh -c "wmctrl -a Calculator || gnome-calculator"
```

you will change the `.desktop` file to behave as "Launch or Switch to". You need the `sh -c "..."` construct here because `.desktop` launchers do not support multiple commands on the `Exec=` line.

To safely change the `.desktop` launchers without the need of being administrator, copy the `.desktop` launchers you want to change to `~/.local/share/applications`. Then you can edit them with your text editor. The changed `.desktop` files under your user home folder replace the ones installed systemwide (for all users) under `/usr/share/applications`.

Personally, I am using [`jumpapp`](https://github.com/mkropat/jumpapp), a bash script that is based on the same principle. It is however more advanced, and will, on subsequent invocations, switch between different windows that may be open.

If that is too complicated for you, try if you can live with the default "full screen" launcher of Ubuntu desktop. I learned to, and use jumpapp for keyboard shortcuts (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> launches or switches to the browser, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> launches or switches to the file manager, etc).

Comment: thank you for your answer i tried jumpapp and it's working , so i'm making custom  launchers(with jumpapp) for the apps that i frequently use so when i run them with alfred it will check if there is an instance of the app :)

Comment: Perfect! Once you know, it is not actually difficult, but it involves some manual configuration. But that is the fun with linux :)